# XNA Microphone in Windows Phone App Doesn't Work When Page is Navigated to a Second Time

Tags: xna, windows-phone, microphone

I have a Windows phone app with a page that uses the XNA Microphone and has a record button and play back button, very similar to any number of tutorials online. When I first navigate to the page the record and play functionality works fine. However, if I click the back button, then navigate to the page again, the sound recorded sounds like a part of the spoken word repeated a couple of times. For example, I'll record "testing" and the playback sounds like "sss...sss". Any ideas?

Comment: could you put up the code you are using for playback and code relating to the audio capturing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The following line is in the page's constructor:

this.MicroPhone.BufferReady += new EventHandler(this.Microphone_BufferReady);

A new page gets constructed on every navigation to the page, therefore the Microphone_BufferReady function in multiple instances of the same page object was getting called and the data from the microphone was occasionally being stored in other instances. The key is to remove the handler in the OnNavigatedFrom page event:

this.MicroPhone.BufferReady -= new EventHandler(this.Microphone_BufferReady);